# React/SCSS/GatsbyJS - Local font not resolving when imported using @font-face

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, gatsby

I am currently receiving errors in two child components of my Gatsbyjs project that import my `global.scss` file where I am attempting to load a local font giving me this error :

`ERROR in ./src/components/elements/Nav/nav.scss Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-ext ract-plugin/dist/loader.js): ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: Can't resolve '../../public/static/fonts/GangsterGroteskRegular.woff2' in '/Projects/src/components/elements/Nav' at finishWithoutResolve`

I have attempted to import the SCSS files more globally using the gatsby-browser.js file but that doesn't seem to filter down to child components.

I have already tried addressing this with Webpack and installing `gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader` as it seems the issue stems from there but nothing has worked thus far.

---

My global.scss file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GangsterGrotesk';
    src: local('GangsterGrotesk'),
        url('../../public/static/fonts/GangsterGroteskRegular.woff2')
            format('woff2');
}


$font: 'GangsterGrotesk' sans-serif;
$font-stack: 'GangsterGrotesk' sans-serif, 'Arial' sans-serif,
    'Helvetica' sans-serif;

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:$font-stack:;
}
```

---

nav.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, withPrefix } from 'gatsby';
import { siteData } from '../../../config/index';
import './nav.scss';

const Nav = () => {
    const { menu } = siteData.navLinks;

    return (
        <nav>
            <Link className="logo" to="/">
                <h4>{siteData.siteTitle}</h4>
            </Link>
            <ul className="nav__list">
                {menu.map(({ name, url }, key) => {
                    return (
                        <li className="nav__item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" key={key} to={url}>
                                {name}
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

---

nav.scss

```
@import '../../../styles/global.scss';

nav {
    padding: 0.25rem 0;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: $col-bg;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px $col-border solid;
    & > * {
        overflow-x: none;
    }
}

.nav__list {
    align-self: center;
}

.nav__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend pointing the`/public` folder to load local fonts. That folder is generated during the build process (`gatsby build`) and won't be always accessible when requesting it in `gatsby develop` for example. I'd recommend using a sourced folder (inside `/src`) or using the static folder, as described in the [using local fonts docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/using-local-fonts/).

For example, using a `/src/fonts/GangsterGroteskRegular.woff2` folder, the approach should be:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "GangsterGrotesk";
  src: url("../fonts/GangsterGroteskRegular.woff2");
}
```

*Note: tweak the local path of `src` rule accordingly*

Then, you will be able to assign `$font`:

```
$font: 'GangsterGrotesk' sans-serif;
```

Comment: This stopped the error which is great. I think the file path being at a higher level was the issue. 

The font will still not display though, it seems to be in the styles when looking in dev tools but with a line through it, so it is not applying.

Comment: This means that the styles are being overriden by another rule. Check your styles import order or the specificity of your rules

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the font
2. Create a Fonts folder in the source directory

> ```
> .src/fonts
> ```

3. Copy the fonts you want to use (e.g. AssistantRegular.ttf) into the ‘fonts‘ directory.
4. In the project’s index.js, import the fonts you want to use.
5. In the projects index.css add the font-face

> @font-face {   font-family: "AssistantRegular";   src:
> local("AssistantRegular"),
> url("./fonts/assistant.regular.ttf") format("truetype");   font-weight: normal; }

> .woff -> format("woff"),
> .ttf -> format("truetype")
> .eot -> format('embedded-opentype')
> .svg#vtks_sonhoregular _> format('svg')

6. Now the font/s are available to the project and can be used in regular CSS etc

> .body {
> font-family: AssistantRegular;
> ...
> }